# Getting line of text after specific string in C#

Tags: c#

I am reading contents of a file that looks something like this

```
[1]
Message=my string here
EffDate=1/1/1995
DeactDate= 
Modified= 
Note=

[2]
Message=my other string here
EffDate=1/1/1995
DeactDate= 
Modified= 
Note=
```

I want to get the string after `Message=` but only to the end of the line. I do not want any of the dates or notes or anything.

I was hoping to put both messages into an array of strings or something like that. Is there any way to do it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working code you need:

```
var d = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            var t = d.Where(g => g.Contains("Message"));
            string[] splited;
            foreach (var item in t)
            {
                splited = item.Split(new string[] { "Message=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                Console.WriteLine(splited[1]);
            }
```

Let me know if you have any confusion.

Comment: You can not use split on **=** since it can be a part of string after Message=.

Comment: @MaheshChand: Have user mentioned that = sign can appear single or multiple times? Why you did down voted it?

Comment: Thank you, very helpful answer. May I ask why I need to call the first index of `splited`? Is the 0th index `Message=`?

Comment: yes. Message= will be at 0th index and rest of the line will be at 1st index.

Comment: @WesThompson Can your `Message` value contain any `=`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use followin approach.

1. Read Your file, best using method ReadAllLines, Please look at [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. After reading You will get collection of Strings, one item per each line.
3. Write method checks if line from file is starting from Message
4. If yes, use String.Split method with "=" sign, and add element of index 1 to Your output collection of messages.

I hope it's understandable.

Comment: You can not use split on **=** since it can be a part of string after Message=.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
string[] getMessages(string file) {
    List<string> messages = new List<string>();

    string[] lines = file.ReadAllLines();       /* read the lines */
    foreach(string line in lines) {
        string[] parts = line.Split('=');
        string contentPart = String.Join("=", parts.Skip(1).ToArray();
        if(parts[0]=="Message")
            messages.Add(contentPart);
    }

    return messages.ToArray();
}
```

Although keep in mind that this is not very elegant nor effective solution. It would be better to parse the whole file, fill an array of structures and then operate on it.

To give a reason **why** I used `Split` instead of anything else: when comparing and trying to list more than just the `Message`, it would become uneffective to use `StartsWith` or `Contains`.

Comment: You can not use split on **=** since it can be a part of string after Message=.

Comment: @MaheshChand That has not been stated. Anyway, I made a correction edit.

Comment: Still, wrong. Also, he did not mention that = will appear only once in that line. To be clear, please have a look at my answer.

Comment: @MaheshChand Why wrong? You know that there can be multiple correct answers, not just yours?

Comment: Your answer would fail if text is like..  Message=my string here and it also contains = and it want it to be in result

Comment: @MaheshChand Have you read the edit? If you had before downvoting, you would notice that there's that part with `String.Join`.. Oh, does it hurt now?

Comment: Your code will give the same output but there are too many unnecessary operations like splitting, skip first, ToArray then Join them

Comment: @MaheshChand Have you `read` the last part? The reason **why**? Or is it too difficult to read english?

Comment: @user35443: He only know how to down vote an answer, I think. I had flagged his "=" comment on my answer. You can also flag him if you think right.

Comment: @SimpleMan Yeah, it seems so.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already reading file than you only need to store the first line in a string which contains string `Message` than split the string with `=`and store in a list.

```
string strFilePath = @"D:\Maraj\Work\Ajax.txt";
FileStream objFS = new FileStream(strFilePath, FileMode.Open);
List<string> list = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(objFS))
  {
    while (Sr.ReadLine() != null)
    {
    string line = Sr.ReadLine();
    if(line.Contains("Message=")
      {
        list.Add(line .Split('=')[1]);
      }
    }
     objFS.Close();
  }
```

Comment: You can not use split on **=** since it can be a part of string after Message=.

Comment: User is has said in question that line will contain "Message=";\

Comment: But he does not said that = will appear only once in that line. To be clear, please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should suffice:

```
string[] messages = File.ReadLines("fileName.txt")
                        .Where(line => line.StartsWith("Message="))
                        .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2)[1])
                        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Read all the lines from text.
2. for each line check if **Message=** exists in start of line.
3. If yes, get the message by using Substring() method

   ```
       var messages = File.ReadAllLines("M:\\m.txt");
       List<string> result = new List<string>();
       foreach (var msg in messages)
       {
           var key = "Message=";
           if (msg.StartsWith(key))
               result.Add(msg.Substring(msg.IndexOf(key) + key.Length));
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple `for` loop:

```
string[] messages = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt"); //read all lines

for (int i = 1; i < messages.Length; i = i + 7) //just get the line containing "Message"
{
    string message = messages[i].Split('=')[1];
    //now you have the message, save it where ever you want.
}
```

Comment: Your answer would fail if text is like.. Message=my string here and it also contains = and it want it to be in result

Comment: @MaheshChand The test cases provided by the OP doesn't contain any `=` other than with the `Message`. We should consider what the OP has stated, and should not go with our assumptions.

Comment: @MaheshChand You should not down vote all the correct answers just because of your assumptions. All the answers are correct with different approaches.